# self.errors is empty but shows error in template

Tags: django-views, django-forms

I can't believe in that:

forms.py:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    field1 = forms.CharField(label='somelabel', max_length=254, widget=forms.TextInput(), required = False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        #Focus on form field whenever error occurred
        logger.error('Warning')
        errorList=list(self.errors)
        logger.error('{}'.format(self.errors))
        for item in errorList:
            self.fields[item].widget.attrs.update({'autofocus': ''})
            break
```

views.py:

```
  if request.method == 'POST':
        form1 = OtherForm(request.POST,prefix='other')
        form2 = MyForm(request.POST, prefix='my')
        if form1.is_valid():
            (...) 
        if form2.is_valid():
             form2.add_error('field1','This is error on field1')

    else:
        form1 = OtherForm( prefix='other')
        form2 = MyForm(prefix='my')

    return render(request,'vote.html', context = {
        'form1':form1,
        'form2':form2,
    })
```

And I can see "This is error on field1" below Field1 in beautiful red color, I can see Warning in debug, but no errors in debug. self.errors is EMPTY...HELP!

Comment: if `form2.is_valid()` means the form is valid. You can indeed use `form2.add_error(..)` but then the `__init__` method is already *finished*. `__init__` runs when you *construct* a `MyForm` object, not each time you update the form.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I assumed, that ''__init__'' runs when I render it via context, but of course you're right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution is to set autofocus just after adding error:

```
form2.add_error('field1','This is error on field1')
form2.fields['field1'].widget.attrs.update({'autofocus': ''})
```